How can I calculate differential via impedances in PCB design?
I am designing a PCB which includes a BGA connector and differential pairs. The differential signals are Displayport and Ethernet. Those tracks go connector to connector only.
I choose 0.2mm drill hole/ 0.45mm via hole via. It is like this photo:

There is no via impedance calculated. I think there is a problem  with the impedance.
I researched how to select my differential vias but I did not find enough info. I want to fanout with the BGA's pads (dog bone connection) for differential pairs, and I want to calculate the impedance of vias like traces.
This is my stack-up. 4 mil track width/4 mil trace space:

I looked at the Saturn PCB tool kit, but I do not understand the parameters like "ref plane opening" and "property selection" buttons:


Perhaps, the following TI article could be useful to you: https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/lit/html/SSZTCR1

@FrancescoM. It does not talk about about how to calculate via sizes. Or even track sizes. In which way that article is useful to the question?

"Ref Plane Opening" refers to the distance of the copper plane (GND) to the via. In the properties secion, you can select "Differential Vias" which might be what you want.

@justmeI understand that the "esat" applicant wishes to calculate the impedance of a line consisting of two metal tracks that is nothing more than a strip line. That article gives the idea that it is an electrical line with its characteristic impedance and that it should be treated as such. Are you the judge of the site? I am not informed, I apologize if I am wrong.

@Justme you right,I wonder how I can calculate and use via impedance in differential pair routing.

The toolkit version is not the latest but it should be usable.
Also the greatest problem is that you are wanting to calculate differential vias, but are not using the differential but single-ended via calculator.
Another question is, you are not really just making differential vias in the middle of a transmission line, so it may be impossible to have correct impedance while fanning out the traces from BGA pins to the layer where the impedance is correct. There will always be a mismatch at the pins on both ends.
The reference plane is usually a ground plane under the traces, or the supply plane - whichever plane you use as reference plane for the signals. You only have 4 layers so top and bottom are high speed signal layers and the two middle layers are reference planes for the signals.
The reference plane opening diameter is how big hole there is in the ref plane copper for the signal via.
Property selection is if you want a differential or single-ended via.
So having said that, the BGA case and amount of layers largely defines what you can do and how to fan out the signals. It might not be possible to have correct impedance on the tracks under the BGA, including vias, and the BGA pins. You might need more PCB layers to achieve what you want in a sensible fashion, without making too many holes in the two middle layers that usually provide ground and supplies.
So switch to Differential Vias and see what kind of values you get.
Also note that the BGA connector may also be quite an impedance mismatch so slightly more mismatch due to fan-out might be irrelevant.
